# Replace Adobe RTSP with html5 and websockets for livestreaming

Tags: video, streaming, flash

The discussion about removing support for Adobe Flash is going on and it looks like sooner or later it will be gone for good.

We run vod and streaming services, which are all depending on Adobes rtsp (Real Time Streaming Protocol).

I think rtsp rocks. It's incedibly fast and reliable. The popular rtsp plugin for nginx is currently under development by Dailymotion, so I think it was a good choise to use rtsp. That was like 2 years ago. Surprise...

I plan to replace rtsp now because I'm sure it will die with flash. Problem: I don't see an alternative for rtsp yet - at least where it comes to livestreaming.

Our users are able to stream live or watch a livestream in good quality without installing additional software.

So let's imagine - Flash will be removed from the internet tomorrow. How can I provide the same services without loss of quality?

Are there any recomendable websocket frameworks for livestreaming?

Also a benefit of rtsp was that users couldn't just download a file. I don't want to do hacks like blocking the right mouse button to prevent that (and when you watch a movie with Android or iPhone you can download the video anyway). The company behind behind the videos it is not interested in delivering their videos for free so I must find a solution.

**What alternative can I use to replace Adobe RTSP?**

Comment: Check out a product called Wowza - can be set up for live or vod ... host yourself or thier saas ... Stream to PCs, Macs, Linux machines, iThings, Androids